# Missing field in table while connecting to db in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Using prepared statement i tried to insert values into table shows **No column name in email** but it was clear i didnt missed email anywhere in my project.

RegistrationAcitivity.java

```
public void reg_submit(View v){

    DataHelper con=new DataHelper(this);
    GetterRegistration model=new GetterRegistration();

        SQLiteDatabase db = con.getWritableDatabase();

        **String sql="insert into registration(name,email,password)values(?,?,?)";**

        SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);

        stmt.bindString(1, model.getName());
        stmt.bindString(2, model.getEmail());
        stmt.bindString(3,  model.getPassword());           
        stmt.execute();
        db.close();
        Intent in = new Intent(this, CocomoActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(in, requestCode);

}
```

}

DataHelper.java

```
 public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "registration";
        public static final String id= "_id";
        public static final String name = "name";
        **public static final String email = "email";**
        public static final String password = "password";

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Database creation sql statement
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_COMMENTS + "( " + id
                + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + name
                + " text not null,"+email
                +"text not null," +password
                +"text not null)";
```

This was the Error report in Logcat

05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  ... 11 more
05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704): Caused by: **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table registration has no column named email: , while compiling: insert into registration(name,email,password)values(?,?,?)**
05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
05-11 15:16:25.785: E/AndroidRuntime(704):  at android.cocomo.login.RegistrationActivity.reg_submit(RegistrationActivity.java:45).

Any help will be appreciated . Thank you in Advance. Still Im trying to fix this if anyone suggestion Let me know friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no space between email and text.

```
 **email+"text** not null," +...
```

and between password and text

Comment: 'private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
  + TABLE_COMMENTS + "( "+id+"integer primary key autoincrement,"+name+"text not null,"+email+"text not null,"+password+
   "text not null)";' Still same problem

Comment: change `name+"text` to `name+" text` and `password+ "text` to `password+ " text`
your current query is like `nametext not null,emailtext not null, passwordtext not null`

Comment: zz this make me crazy.. now i removed all string directly i entered the query... `private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table registration (_id integer primary key autoincrement,name text not null,email text not null,password text not null);";` Still error

Comment: Now you have an extra ';' in your database_create string in the end.

Comment: Drop the table before changing the create table query. As SQLiteOpenHelper  onCreate wont be called unless you change the database version.

Comment: @Taurn i fixed that error this the code i entered `
   SQLiteDatabase db = con.getWritableDatabase();
   //db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
   ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
   cv.put(name, name1);
   cv.put(emailtext, email1);
   cv.put(passwordtext, password1);
   
   db.insert(TABLE_COMMENTS, name,cv);` Thanks for your help